# Mautik hosting best practice

Tags: mautic

I am new to Mautik and therefore need a guidance on the same.

Where should we setup mautik... on some folder or on sub domain to main site or a separate domain? How does the landing pages and forms gets its URL? Can it be embedded on another site on another domain or is it required to be hosted where mautik is hosted?

Moreover does single installation of mautik can be used for two or more different businesses site... which are not relevant.. and mainly a different customer for a marketing company? Or is it better to install mautik per business?

Can we track interactions from mobile app too using mautik?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, I expect you  are talking about Mautic and not Mautik.

1. You are free to choose whatever type of hosting you want, personally I Like to use independent container(could be lightweight) however I have seen people hosting on shared hosting as well.
2. If you are hosting on say example.com the landing page url will be example.com/landing-page same goes for all elements of mautic.
3. Yes forms can be embedded on other websites with a completely different domain. say example-something-else.com, you will need to put your tracking script on other site's head to make it work better. I for example check out this small tutorial https://tutorialsjoint.com/mautic-wordpress-integration/ it shows how you can use it in wordpress.
4. No it is not required that wherever you want to use mautic form should be on same host or domain.
5. However I recommend to use subdomain if usually just to save the hassle of buying a new domain and keeping the landing page urls more relevant. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8lWaCabH1w this video shows how tracking works, it'll help you understand little better. Also here's official documentation: https://docs.mautic.org/en/contacts/manage-contacts/contact-monitoring.
6. You can use use one instance to manage multiple businesses I know people who are doing it but when the number of contacts, segments, campaigns, form, emails, landing pages grow with time it becomes a hassle to keep it clean. You can use category and a specific naming convention to keep them organized. But in a good way i will recommend to keep different instances in long run.
7. I am not sure about mobile apps but ideally it should be possible using tracking script or tracking pixel, perhaps you will need to turn off CORS restrictions.

I hope it was helpful.
Cheers!

Comment: Thank you Mayank for your answer. This clears lot of things for us.

Comment: can you also help us personally setting up and configure Mautic?

Comment: HI Krunal, I can't help you personally because of time constraint but you will find a guy kishan kumawat on facebook or linkedin company name is bizcrony. He will help you for sure.

Answer (score -1):

No, you must use a VPS with Devian or Ubuntu, In a shared hosting it can cause problems. If you send many emails.

Landing pages can be made in html and pasted or edited in Mautic.

To use it in more sites you must create a user for each one, with their respective different email.

Comment: Please help to translate your post into English as StackOverflow is an English-only site.

Comment: ok, i translated it